# seedstack, how to read the base url from properties file

Tags: seedstack

I am using feign client for doing rest call.I kept my base url in application .yaml file.
But I want application.yaml should read the base url from properties file kept in external location.
I am facing this issue when I am trying to do the deployment of my web application.

Answer (score 0):

SeedStack configuration files can contain placeholders (or macros as we call them). Some runtime information is available under the `runtime` configuration node and can be referenced using macros.

This is the case for the base URL if you run your Web application with the embedded Web server. You can refer to it from your properties files regardless of their location:

```
someProperty=${runtime.web.baseUrl}/something
```

**Warning**: in SeedStack versions older than 18.11, the base URL is available under `web.runtime.baseUrl` instead. This has been changed in the latest version to regroup all runtime information in the same place. Note that it also had a trailing slash back then.

Relevant docs:

- Macros: http://seedstack.org/docs/core/configuration/#macros
- Web runtime info: http://seedstack.org/docs/web/#runtime-information
- Release notes about the change: http://seedstack.org/posts/18.11-release-notes/#runtime-information-update